# How to filter and show sheet data in html webapp table

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am using below function to display in google sheet data in the webapp, how can i filter and show the data based on the date mentioned in body  ...?

Example:- in  i have some date on load data should get filtered and show only respective date data

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
  <h1>Date:7/23/2020</h1>
    <? var data = getData(); ?>
    <table>
      <? for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { ?>
        <tr>
          <? for (var j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++) { ?>
            <td><?= data[i][j] ?></td>
          <? } ?>
        </tr>
      <? } ?>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is your HTML always hardcoded for `<h1>Date:7/23/2020</h1>` or does that change?  If it changes, does it change during the template evaluation or can the web app user (client side) change the date?

Comment: it change during the template evaluation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter your array of arrays using [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and a function that accepts an array of values and returns a boolean.

You can add this inline and inside the HTML template,

```js
var data = getData().filter(function(){/* function body */});
```

but this can be hard to read inside the template, so I suggest creating the function dynamically by passing in the current date and getting the predicate function returned so it looks like this:

```js
var data = getDate().filter(byDate(dateString));
```

In your server code (`.gs`) file:

```js
function getData() {
  // returns sheet values[][]
}

const DATE_COLUMN = 0; // set to what your date column is

/**
 * @param {string} dateString - should match server's `toLocaleDateString` output
 */
function byDate(dateString) {
  return function(row) {
    return row[DATE_COLUMN].toLocaleDateString() === dateString;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
  <h1>Date:<?= dateString ?></h1>
    <? var data = getData().filter(byDate(dateString)); ?>
    <table>
      <? for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { ?>
        <tr>
          <? for (var j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++) { ?>
            <td><?= data[i][j] ?></td>
          <? } ?>
        </tr>
      <? } ?>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Dear --- Working --- Thanks AGAIN